# Function $f(x)=2e^x/(1+e^x)$ and its critical point

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Looking at the graph of $$\frac{2e^{x}}{1+e^{x}},$$ there is a critical point at $x=0$ with an undefined derivative. The problem that I have is to find the critical point algebraically:

$$f'(x)=\frac{2e^{x}}{(1+e^{x})^{2}} = 0 \implies e^{x}=-1 \text{ or } e^{x}=0$$
To my knowledge there no values of $x$ that would make those two equations true.

Am I mistaken in my approach/calculations, or is there something that i do not know yet?

Comment: There is no critical point. The graph is nice at $x=0$, and everywhere  else.

Answer (score 3):

We have $$f'(x) = \frac{2e^x}{(e^x + 1)^2} $$

An undefined derivative means that $$e^x + 1 = 0 \iff e^x = -1$$

The above equation has no real solution and hence we conclude that there is no point of the function with an undefined derivative. There are no critical points either since $e^x \neq 0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

The graph of your function is quite nicely behaved at $x=0$ and everywhere else as can be seen below: [image]

In fact, we second derivative reveals that $$f''(x) = -\frac{2e^x(e^x - 1)}{(1+e^x)^3}$$ so that $f''(0) = 0$, further investigation reveals that $x=0$ is in fact a point of inflection.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative is not $0$ at $x=0$, therefore it is not a critical point. However the derivative has a maximum at $x=0$. This means that the second derivative is equal to zero, and that the function goes from convex to concave.